# Adjust microphone volume in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: alsa, gui, microphone

I know I can adjust microphone volume using alsamixer from the command line, but is there a GUI utility for doing that, similar to the way one adjusts the output volume?  (This is only a matter of aesthetics, I'll admit.)

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the loudspeaker-icon in the notification-area in the task-bar.
This will open a menu with sliders to adjust the volume of playback-devices and capture-devices. Your microphone will be one of the capture-devices.